# Essentially etale but not etale morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the section 2.8 of Lei Fu's "Etale Cohomology Theory", the author introduces a term "essentialy etale":

> A local homomorphism $A\to A'$ is called *essentially etale* if there exists an etale $A$-algebra $B$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $B$ lying above the maximal ideal of $A$ such that $A'$ is $A$-isomorphic to $B_\mathfrak{p}$.

We can easily check that every etale $A$-algebra $A'$ is essentially etale over $A$, since we can take $B=A'$ and $\mathfrak{p}= \mathfrak{m}_{A'}$ (the maximal ideal of $A'$). My question is about the converse. More precisely:

Can we construct an *essentially etale but not etale* morphism? If it is possible (I think this is of course possible, since otherwise there would be no difference between essentially etale and ordinary etale), how can we get an example of such a morphism?

Thank you!

Comment: Essentially etale is equivalent to pro-etale, which is definitely not equivalent to etale, so a counterexample must exist. Unfortunately I'm a little rusty on my pro-etale knowledge, so I don't have one at hand for you.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for providing me useful information! Could you tell me some literature that contains proof of the equivalence of pro-etale and essentially etale?

Comment: Well, a pro-étale morphism that is not étale is $\underline{S}\times Spec(k)$ (this is an inverse limit of affine schemes and $\underline{S}$ is some non-discrete profinite Set)

Comment: @Notone This example is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you for commenting!

Comment: For the result I mentioned, see proposition B.5 in [On the Rational Motivic Homotopy Category](https://www.preschema.com/papers/minus.pdf) by Deglise, Fasel, Khan, and Jin.

Comment: @KReiser I really appreciate your help.